# Use Webstorm to preview the project, always show the following tips, how to fix it?

Tags: jquery, webstorm

Use Webstorm to preview the project, always show the following tips, and Jquery not works, but I open the website directly, the Jquery works, what is the problem? how to fix the Webstorm? Thanks

```
tips:
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined               jquery-1.8.2.js:95
```

Image link :http://np.cdnway.com/images/2015/07/13/55a318edb0062.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have to add jQuery to the list of libraries that you project uses, so that WebStorm knows that you're using it and can use it as a reference.

I don't normally like to solely link to an external site, but there's too much on there to post in here, so I'll just point you to the [jetbrains blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/) on this topic.

Comment: I can not upload Images, The tips image link: http://img.hb.aicdn.com/3ad79186e0ae4ac39b3ae4c87990efa6628c6b552e1d4-lfXhtA

Comment: That link is inaccessible

Comment: sorry, this link maybe deleted by the editor, try this: http://np.cdnway.com/images/2015/07/13/55a318edb0062.jpg    thanks

Comment: Yes, this is the Chrome console, when I use Webstorm to preview the website, console show these error, but open the website directly,jQuery works well

Comment: Ah. I've never used WebStorm to preview a website. I thought you were originally talking about WebStorm's in-code reference errors. Sorry I couldn't help.